# Hierarchical summing in python

Tags: python, recursion

Given the following array:

```
a = []
a.append({'c': 1, 'v': 10, 'p': 4})
a.append({'c': 2, 'v': 10, 'p': 4})
a.append({'c': 3, 'v': 10, 'p': None})
a.append({'c': 4, 'v': 0, 'p': None})
a.append({'c': 5, 'v': 10, 'p': 1})
a.append({'c': 6, 'v': 10, 'p': 1})
```

Where c = code, v= value and p=parent
table looks like that:

```
c v   p
1     4
2 10  4
3 10
4
5 10  1
6 10  1
```

I have to sum up each parent with the values of it's children
Expected result table would be:

```
c v   p
1 20  4
2 10  4
3 10
4 30
5 10  1
6 10  1
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: No, the expected result for 4 is 30 as 1 is parent of 5 and 6 (so it sums up to 20. 4 is parent of 1 and 2. As 1 is sum of 5 and 6 + 2 (wich has a value of 10, so 10 + 10 + 10 = 30

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But there seems to be an inconsistency in your example In the code, `1` has value `10`, but in the table it has value `0`

Comment: True.You're right. Actually the table is the valide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should derive another dictionary, mapping parents to lists of their children, instead of children to their parents. You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this.

```
from collections import defaultdict
children = defaultdict(list)
for d in a:
    children[d["p"]].append(d["c"])
```

Also, I suggest another dictionary, mapping codes to their values, so you don't have to search the entire list each time:

```
values = {}
for d in a:
    values[d["c"]] = d["v"]
```

Now you can very easily define a recursive function for calculating the total value. Note, however, that this will do some redundant calculations. If your data is much larger, you might want to circumvent this by using a bit of memoization.

```
def total_value(x):
    v = values[x]
    for c in children[x]:
        v += total_value(c)
    return v
```

Finally, using this function in a dict comprehension gives you the total values for each code:

```
>>> {x: total_value(x) for x in values}
{1: 30, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 40, 5: 10, 6: 10}
```

Comment: Actually the dictionary is already given (in fact it's a collection of rows of an odoo tree). Let's think about the account of an accounting where the higher level accounts are summing up the lower level values. I cannot tell you how many children each parent will have. That's why the parent code is defined at the child level. I hope now I was clear

Comment: @Gabor No, not too clear, I'm afraid. Do you meant that you can not get the entire list of children for any given parent? In this case, how would you get the total value? Have you tried whether my approach works? If not, what's the problem?

Comment: I needed some time to understand your solution but at the end of the day I got it. :-) Your solution gives the right result. It would have been more elegant to avoid those additional dicts but as long as it gives me the right result, I don't care. Thanks.